# Как убрать рывки при прокрутке страницы?

Tags: css, браузер, mac, safari

На странице используются блоки с фиксированным фоном. Во всех браузерах прокрутка плавная. А вот в браузере Сафари страница прокручивается с рывками. Как можно это исправить? Благодарю!

```css
p {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
}

.cover {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.cover:before {
  z-index: 2;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  background: url(http://www.fullhdoboi.ru/_ph/6/227497508.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<div class="cover"></div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Странно, я не вижу рывков -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убрать "подергивание" фиксированного фона при прокрутке страницы в браузерах Сафари и Internet Explorer можно следующим образом:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
        $('body').on("mousewheel", function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var wd = event.wheelDelta;
            var csp = window.pageYOffset;
            window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
        });
}
});
```